# Склонение дробных числительных

Tags: морфология

Как склоняются дробные числительные, например: две целых и одна шестая?

Comment: числитель склоняется как количественноеи , акзнаменатель как порядковое

Comment: Да, но автор вопроса, видимо, не знает, как именно склоняются порядковые и количественные. И потом есть ещё челая часть.

Answer (score 2):

Дроби сложны лишь тем, что они одновременно состоят и из количественных числительных (в числителе), и из порядковых (в знаменателе). Чтобы просклонять любую дробь, числитель нужно склонять как обычное количественное числительное, а знаменатель — как порядковое. При этом в составных количественных числительных склоняются все слова, а в составных порядковых — только последнее.

И.п. - две целых и одна шестая, Р.п. - двух целых и одной шестой, Д.п. - двум целым и одной шестой, В.п. - две целых и одной шестой, Т.п. - двумя целыми и одной шестой, П.п. - двух целых и одной шестой.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, в чем затруднения, поэтому могу только просклонять.

И. две целых и одна шестая
Р. двух целых и одной шестой
Д. двум целым и одной шестой
В. две целых и одну шестую
Т. двумя целыми и одной шестой
П. (о) двух целых и одной шестой

Если та будет понятнее подставляйте каждый раз слова часть, части:

И. две целых (части) и одна шестая (часть) 
Р. двух целых (части) и одной шестой (части)
Д. двум целым (частям) и одной шестой (части)
...

В именительном, кстати, возможно как "две целых", так и "две целые", но это для числительных, заканчивающихся на два, три и четые.

Comment: В предложном падеже - о ДВУХ целых и одной шестой :-))