# Дробные числительные

Tags: морфология

Как склоняются дробные числительные: 0,7;  2,03;  1,1;  1/25?

Answer (score 2):

Общее правило я уже привела в предыдущем ответе на подобный же Ваш вопрос [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/8775/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85). В заключение — исключение. Речь о частном случае дробей с целыми значениями, например: *ноль целых двести сорок три тысячных*. Если в дроби целых единиц — ноль, то при её склонении слово «целых» не изменяется. *Температура приблизилась к нолю целых пяти десятым градуса.* В общем же случае прилагательное «целых» склоняется. *Победил с шестьюдесятью тремя целыми шестью десятыми процента.*
Используя правило, думаю, нетрудно просклонять все ваши дроби. Правило - это удочка, а рыбу ловить извольте сами.